# Unhandled Exception: type 'PlatformException' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart

- Using Google sign in API for a month now
- Getting this error before google sign-in
- Changed Cloud Firestore Rules, still showing the same results
- API error? (sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10:, null)

---

```
E/flutter ( 8552): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: type 'PlatformException' is not a subtype of type 'String'
E/flutter ( 8552): #0      _SignInState.initState.<anonymous closure> (package:event_management/google_signin.dart:35:32)
E/flutter ( 8552): #1      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
E/flutter ( 8552): #2      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter ( 8552): #3      _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:160:20)
E/flutter ( 8552): #4      Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:708:47)
E/flutter ( 8552): #5      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:729:24)
E/flutter ( 8552): #6      Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:537:5)
E/flutter ( 8552): #7      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.completeError (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:47:15)
E/flutter ( 8552): #8      GoogleSignIn.signInSilently (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart)
E/flutter ( 8552): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8552): #9      _SignInState.initState (package:event_management/google_signin.dart:32:13)
E/flutter ( 8552): #10     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4684:58)
E/flutter ( 8552): #11     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:5)
E/flutter ( 8552): #12     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3490:14)
E/flutter ( 8552): #13     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3258:18)
E/flutter ( 8552): #14     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5874:14)
E/flutter ( 8552): #15     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3490:14)
E/flutter ( 8552): #16     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3258:18)
E/flutter ( 8552): #17     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4571:16)
E/flutter ( 8552): #18     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4262:5)
E/flutter ( 8552): #19     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4525:5)
E/flutter ( 8552): #20     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:5)
E/flutter ( 8552): #21     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3490:14)
E/flutter ( 8552): #22     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3258:18)
E/flutter ( 8552): #23     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5874:14)
E/flutter ( 8552): #24     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3490:14)
E/flutter ( 8552): #25     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3258:18)
E/flutter ( 8552): #26     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5874:14)
E/flutter ( 8552): #27     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3490:14)
E/flutter ( 8552): #28     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3258:18)
E/flutter ( 8552): #29     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4571:16)
E/flutter ( 8552): #30     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4719:11)
E/flutter ( 8552): #31     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4262:5)
E/flutter ( 8552): #32     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4525:5)
E/flutter ( 8552): #33     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4710:11)
E/flutter ( 8552): #34     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:5)
E/flutter ( 8552): #35     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3490:14)
E/flutter ( 8552): #36     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3258:18)
E/flutter ( 8552): #37     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5874:14)
E/flutter ( 8552): #38     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3490:14)
E/flutter ( 8552): #39     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3258:18)
E/flutter ( 8552): #40     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5874:14)
E/flutter ( 8552): #41     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3490:14)
E/flutter ( 8552): #42     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3258:18)
E/flutter ( 8552): #43     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4571:16)
E/flutter ( 8552): #44     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4719:11)
E/flutter ( 8552): #45     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4262:5)
E/flutter ( 8552): #46     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package
```

---

### Cloud Firestore Rules:

`

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2020, 8, 31);
    }
  }
}
```

`

Comment: From the error message, it seems like you did something like `print(PlatformException)` instead of `print(PlatformException.toString())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause:

- This Problem occured as I had re-installed Android Studio in my external ssd, so SHA-1 values changed.

Solution:

- **Get SHA-1 again using "gradlew signingReport" command in gradlew terminal.**
- **Add new SHA-1 value into the Firebase, it might solve your issue.**